# How long do I have left to save Bottle & Cappy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

With the last update of Fallout Shelter, Bethesda has added these "limited time" quests.

Question is, how limited is that time exactly? What happens when the quests "end", will it still be possible to get the benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the typical use of the term "limited time only," I'd guess that these quests have some determined time where they will no longer be available to do.

I checked in the game itself and online and there are no specified end dates for these limited time quests, but I'd err on the side of caution and do them as soon as possible to make sure you don't lose out on any rewards!

**EDIT:**

I just received a notification from Fallout Shelter with the following message:

> It's the final weekend to play the Labor Dispute quest and get a Rare Dweller, Lunchbox and more! Start the quest now before it's gone forever.

This confirms my earlier answer as well as give some insight into how long limited time quests will last, since apparently you will be notified when the deadline is approaching.

Comment: I never got the notification, but I had a hunch that yesterday would be a good time to complete the quest "just in case". Good timing as it turns out! Didn't get to do the Labor Dispute one though :-( those limited quests aren't a very good idea in a single player game IMHO, doest make sense.

Comment: It's to get you to use your Cola and buy more if you run out.

Answer (score 1):

It's been one year ago now that I've asked this question, and coincidentally I've restarted playing Fallout Shelter just recently.

The bottle and cappy quest is still available, and I'm starting to think that "limited time" in this case actually means time counting from the moment you start a vault or perhaps build the overseer's office. How much time you actually have to do them is still unclear.