# When do the time-limited quests expire?

Tags: fallout-shelter

There are certain quest series (like Nabbed from Nuka-World) that have the "Limited Time" Tag.
**When do they expire?**
[image: Quest List]

Comment: Related? [How long do I have left to save Bottle & Cappy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284925/how-long-do-i-have-left-to-save-bottle-cappy)